# C# read byte array from SerialPort

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, usb, serial-communication

I would like to ask why does my program only returns the first byte instead of all byte. My USB port will be sending a byte value of 23, however, when the c# program reads it, it receives a value of 2. Why is that happening? The c# code is as below

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
        port.Open();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2];

        port.Read(buffer, 0, 2);
        HandleSerialData(buffer);

        port.Close();
    }

    private void HandleSerialData(byte[] respBuffer)
    {
        string one, two;
        char a, b;

        a = Convert.ToChar(respBuffer[0]);
        b = Convert.ToChar(respBuffer[1]);

        one = Convert.ToString(a);
        two = Convert.ToString(b);

        MessageBox.Show(one + two);            
    }
```

Comment: Did you send 0x32 or 0x23?

Comment: Hmm... very unlikely... if what the `C#` shows is `2`, then it must receive `0x32` instead of `0x23` - can you confirm again? Or else, what you send is *not* byte `23` *but* ASCII string (2 chars) `2` and `3`. It seems like your `C#` actually receives *two* bytes instead of *one* - at least from the code.

Comment: Ignoring the return value of Read() is **always** wrong.  Serial ports are slow, you usually only get 1 byte.  You certainly will when you read immediately after opening the port.  So the most obvious explanation is that you sent "23" and only got the first character.  Understanding the difference between bytes and characters is pretty crucial.

Comment: yes. you are right. so what should i do to get 2 byte? @HansPassant

Comment: Keep calling Read().  Since you only want two for some otherwise mysterious reason you can simply call Read(buffer, 1, 1) if the previous one did not return 2.

Comment: thanks. it's work now. @HansPassant